# Unable to launch VsCode

Tags: snap, visual-studio-code

I tried to launch vscode several times from my project directory. This is the error I get each time:

```
/snap/code/129/usr/share/code/bin/code: 62: /snap/code/129/usr/share/code/bin/../code: not found
```

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall several times. Still no luck. I am a relatively new user and hence I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Confirm the correct installation path: The error message suggests that the path to the VSCode executable is not found or incorrect.    `ls /usr/share/code`

Comment: Yes you are right. It says no file or directory when I check at usr/share/code

Comment: It means that the code is not installed correctly, try launching VSCode using the Snap package manager with the following command: `snap run code`

Comment: No luck. Exactly the same error as before.

Comment: Reinstall VSCode: If the above steps didn't resolve the issue:

    `sudo snap remove code`
    `sudo snap remove --purge code`
`sudo snap install code --classic`

Comment: I have tried that. It does uninstall each time and reinstalls sucessfully. `code b3e4e68a from Visual Studio Code (vscode✓) installed`

But it does not launch after that.

Comment: check it the folder exist `ls /usr/share/code`, if not, means there is problem in installation of vscode. trying using either of the command  `sudo snap install code --classic`
    `sudo snap install --classic vscode` , one at a time, second after removing the package

Comment: No luck. `sudo snap install code --classic` works as usual but does not launch. `sudo snap install --classic vscode` does not work. Output is : 
`snap "vscode" is not available on stable but is available to install on the following channels:`

Comment: have to tried `sudo snap install code --channel=<channel-name>`  Replace <channel-name> with the desired channel name from the list of available channels provided in the message

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in the end I had to completely purge snapd from my system and reinstall like this:

```
sudo apt purge snapd && sudo apt install snapd
```

I ran into the following issue while I was doing that:

```
error : cannnot perform the following tasks :
remove data for the official snap "firefox" (1969) (Unlinkat /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_US.aff: read-only file system)
```

To get around this I had to unmount 'host-hunspell'

```
umount /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
```

I was then able to reinstall all my snap applications.